# How to re-trigger an if-else statement after store update in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm using a string list as a store in a component I'm building (`favourites`):

```js
<script lang="ts">
      let favorites: string[] = [];
      let listingsList: any = [];
     
      function favourite(listingID: string) {
          // do some stuff
          favourites.push(listingID) 
}
</script>
```

It keeps track of some component `ids`, so I can show a different `button` depending if the `id` is on the list or not.

The idea is when I click the button, the favourites list get's updated and then the other button should be displayed:

```html
{#each listingsList as listing}
    {#if favorites?.includes(listing.id)}
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" on:click={() => favourite(listing?.id)}>Saved</button>
    {:else}
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" on:click={() => favourite(listing?.id)}>Save it!</button>
    {/if}
{/each}
```

**The issue:**

If I click the button, I can see the list being updated, logging it on the console, but the button does not change. If I refresh the page, the other button shows, as expected.

So my question is, is this expected behaviour? Is there any way to trigger again the `if` after the list get's update to change the button right away?

Comment: https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive

Comment: amazing @Corrl! thanks! still can't believe how I missed it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Corrl points out in his comment, the issue is that `.push()` don't trigger updates

> Because Svelte's reactivity is based on assignments, using array
> methods like .push() and .splice() won't automatically trigger
> updates. A subsequent assignment is required to trigger the update.
> This and more details can also be found in the tutorial.

The solution is to re-assign the variable after the update:

```js
favorites.push(listingID);
favorites = favorites;
```